# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame : Videoclassification

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I'm working on a video classification model and have encountered an error when trying to create a training dataset using the labeled_video_dataset function from PyTorchVideo.

Here's an overview of what I've done so far:

I loaded a dataset from Google Drive that contains video files.
I created labels for these videos (0 for "Normal" and 1 for "Shoplifting").
I turned this data into a Pandas DataFrame, where each row contains the video file path and its corresponding label.
I split this DataFrame into a training set (train_df) and a validation set (val_df) using train_test_split.
Now, I want to create a training dataset for my video classification model using the following code:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from pytorchvideo.data import labeled_video_dataset

# Create a training dataset
train_dataset = labeled_video_dataset(
    df,  # Provide the DataFrame directly
    clip_sampler=make_clip_sampler(clipmode, video_duration),
    transform=video_transform,
    decode_audio=False
)

# Create a DataLoader for the training dataset
train_loader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_workers=0,
    pin_memory=True
)
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
```

I have already installed all the necessary libraries and modules, and the DataFrame df appears to be correctly formatted. Can someone please help me identify the issue and provide guidance on how to resolve it?

Here is more code for context:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

base_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Shoplifting Dataset (2022) - CV Laboratory MNNIT Allahabad/Shoplifting Dataset (2022) - CV Laboratory MNNIT Allahabad/Dataset/Dataset/'

normal_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'Normal')
shoplifting_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'Shoplifting')

if os.path.exists(normal_path) and os.path.exists(shoplifting_path):
    normal_files = [os.path.join(normal_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(normal_path) if filename.endswith('.mp4')]
    shoplifting_files = [os.path.join(shoplifting_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(shoplifting_path) if filename.endswith('.mp4')]

    # Create label lists
    normal_labels = [0] * len(normal_files)
    shoplifting_labels = [1] * len(shoplifting_files)

    # Combine the lists of paths and labels
    all_files = normal_files + shoplifting_files
    all_labels = normal_labels + shoplifting_labels

    # Create a DataFrame
    data = {'Video_Path': all_files, 'Label': all_labels}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Print the first 5 rows
    print(df.head())
else:
    print(f"One or both of the directories '{normal_path}' and '{shoplifting_path}' do not exist.")



from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_df, val_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.25)
```

I get the error in this section:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset,ConcatDataset,default_collate
from torch.utils.data import DistributedSampler
from pytorchvideo.data import labeled_video_dataset

# Create a training dataset
train_dataset = labeled_video_dataset(
    df,  # Provide the DataFrame directly
    clip_sampler=make_clip_sampler(clipmode, video_duration),
    transform=video_transform,
    decode_audio=False
)

# Create a DataLoader for the training dataset
train_loader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_workers=0,
    pin_memory=True
)
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happened.  Please provide the full error traceback message.